# Using WiX, how can I download a dependency when the initial URL failed to download

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I'd like to provide my WiX bundle an alternate download(s) URL for grabbing dependencies. I haven't been able to track down documentation on this scenario, so I don't even know if it's possible outside of a hackish Custom Action workaround. Right now, when any attempted download fails, the installation fails, as intended. I'd like it to simply try the next URL(s) with public or internal mirrors if the initial attempt fails until it either succeeds or hard-fails from none of them working. I already have normal dependency packages implemented. I'm just not sure where to go from here to achieve this design. I'd like to do it outside of custom actions, if possible.

Current code example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
    <Fragment>
<!-- Check registry keys for Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable -->
    <util:RegistrySearch Root="HKLM"
                         Key="SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Products\1af2a8da7e60d0b429d7e6453b3d0182"
                         Result="exists"
                         Variable="MVC2005Present_x64"
                         Win64="yes"/>

<!-- Package to deploy Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable (x64) -->
      <ExePackage Id="MVC2005Exe_x64"
                  Name="Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable Package (x64)"
                  Cache="no"
                  Compressed="no"
                  PerMachine="yes"
                  DownloadUrl="https://download.microsoft.com/download/8/B/4/8B42259F-5D70-43F4-AC2E-4B208FD8D66A/vcredist_x64.EXE"
                  Permanent="yes"
          InstallCommand="/q"
          RepairCommand="/q"
          DetectCondition="MVC2005Present_x64"
          InstallCondition="DeployDependencies = 1">
        <RemotePayload CertificatePublicKey="5C499B10F7EF186DC729991A262AB52066423909"
                       CertificateThumbprint="93859EBF98AFDEB488CCFA263899640E81BC49F1"
                       Description="Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable (x64) Setup"
                       Hash="EE916012783024DAC67FC606457377932C826F05"
                       ProductName="Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable (x64)"
                       Size="3175832"
                       Version="6.0.2900.2180" />
        <ExitCode Behavior="scheduleReboot" Value="1641" />
        <ExitCode Behavior="scheduleReboot" Value="3010" />
      </ExePackage>
    </Fragment>
  </Wix>
```

[image]

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this one?  Care to share a solution?

Comment: @Matt it's been a couple years, but IIRC, I used a custom action to handle the download & installation if the payload failed. My other alternative was using a custom bootstrapper per Bob's answer, and I just didn't have time back then to dive into WiX deep enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Burn supports one download URL per payload. A custom bootstrapper application gets an `OnResolveSource` callback where it can supply an alternate download location when the one authored in the bundle fails.

Comment: Let me make sure I understand you correctly. I would have to write a custom bootstrapper to leverage OnResolveSource? Is there no way I can achieve this or something functionally similar using the default bootstrapper? Right now I'm using WixStandardBootstrapperApplication and would really rather not create a custom one if I can help it.

Comment: WixStdBA doesn't support the feature you want. You could add it to WixStdBA if you didn't want to write an entire BA.

Comment: That sounds like a great alternative! How would I start to go about doing that?

Comment: Take a look at http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/ under Development. The wix-devs mailing list would be a good place to ask questions; plenty of people there have done work in WixStdBA.